# How do I add a texture to a model in 2.82?

Tags: texturing

I've been a Blender user for a few years at this point, and I finally just switched over to 2.82 after having used the version in my system's package repo for a while.  Now, I can't find gosh darn anything and I'm starting to get frustrated.

I can find the Materials window, and I can add a material.  But I've been looking for ten minutes now and I cannot for the life of me find where to add a texture.  Can someone please tell me where to find that setting, preferably with screenshots?

Update 3-6-20:  Here is a screenshot of my window.  The first response shows a tab or button that just isn't there on my interface.
(Like I said, I've been using blender for years.  I've already looked in all the places where it would actually make sense for it to be)

[image: window]

Comment: Even if this question is a duplicate, the question linked is completely irrelevant as I am **not using cycles**.  I would prefer if someone would find a better question to mark this as duplicate with or instead unmark it.

Comment: You should explain why the indicated "duplicate" answer does not meet your needs. + texture is not image texture in Cycles or Eevee (but you maybe ask another question about that). I suppose the point is to switch from blender internal to 2.8 which has no more BI?

Comment: I literally just said why.  The "duplicate" answer is A.) for Blender Cycles, and B.) for version 2.8, which uses a different interface.  Logically it should be in the analogous place, but my screenshot shows that it is not.  The answer given below shows a button that isn't in my interface, so I can't accept that answer either.  To clarify, I used to be perfectly able to add textures using the method shown in that answer, but it no longer applies due to the changed interface.

Comment: ok... not sure to understand all your situation. You're using 2.8 right? If yes, the indicated "duplicate" link should do. If not please indicate this is not the case. The most I can do for now is voting for reopening your question. But since I don't understand what is the problem, I won't (as I still do not understand why this previous answer does not fit your situation). Again, in 2.8 for either Cycles or Eevee, textures are not to be an input for shaders.

Comment: I have said, three times now, that the duplicate link is inadequate.  Both the duplicate link and the answer given below, before I posted my image to clarify, show settings that **do not exist** in my version of Blender.  I would like to know if there is another way to access these settings, or if I can somehow re-enable the texture tab if it was disabled by default, or **literally anything** other than just repeating that this question is a duplicate when I have iterated numerous times that it is not.  I apologise for my tone, but I am a bit frustrated at this point.

Comment: And this is the third time now I answer "could you explain why?"... Consider we try to help (for nothing) so if people just dont understand the problem there is a reason...

Comment: In 2.8 as Blender Internal is no more here, the is no "texture input" to place in the shader. Or are you still using 2.79?

Comment: You know what?  I'll just rephrase my question and ask again in a different post, since this post seems to be getting nowhere and my repeated attempts at clarification are not working.  Thank you for your continued patience.

Comment: ok, you can ask another one or edit this one. Advice: indicate clearly why the linked dup question is not suitable for your situation. Also which is your version of Blender (seen the capture, i think this is 2.8?).

Answer (score 4):

The texture button is here (not available in edit mode):

[image]

To add a new texture, click here:

[image]

I strongly suggest to have a look at tutorials on youtube like this one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-ncKGhDih8

Comment: This did not answer my question.  I updated my original post with clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be your exact problem, but other's searching this problem may experience this. I found that when I added a new scene the texture tab is also missing. This is a known issue (https://developer.blender.org/T73611).

The workaround suggested there (and worked for me in 3.2) is to add a mesh object and go into "Texture Paint" mode. It appears blender is coded to not initialize the texture panel until it's needed.

[image]