# Texture tab seemingly missing in Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing

As I asked in [my previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168973/how-do-i-add-a-texture-to-a-model-in-2-82?noredirect=1#comment285117_168973), I cannot find the texture tab on my object settings panel in Blender 2.82.
However, I have found that this is not universal, as other people seem to be able to access it from the position that I had expected it to be in.
Here is a screenshot of the expected interface:

[image: Expected]

Here is a screenshot of my interface:

[image: Mine]

As you can see in the images, **the texture tab is not present in my interface**.  How can I access these settings or make this tab appear in my interface?

*Please do not mark this question as a duplicate unless this question was answered for Blender 2.8.  I have a lot of difficulty navigating the new interface, and unless you can explain how another answer is applicable I will not be able to make use of it.*

Comment: what object do you have selected?

Answer (score 2):

This entire saga was stupid, but I'm posting the answer because I don't want anyone similarly confused to be lost if they try to google it.

I was in edit mode, and as of Blender 1.79 and later you can't add a texture in edit mode.  This is a new and honestly pointless restriction, but if you go into object mode it should be accessible.